# Kernel panic in Fedora 18 after updating to kernel-3.9

Tags: kernel, upgrade, kernel-panic, fedora

I've installed Fedora 18 and did `yum update` to update my system.

I got a bunch of updates (around 350 MB download), among them is `kernel-3.9.4-200.fc18.x86_64`.

Now, when I boot my system to the new added boot entry with the new kernel I get the following kernel panic message:

[image]

I tried to remove the kernel by:

```
yum remove kernel-3.9.4-200.fc18.x86_64
```

Then reboot and do another update:

```
yum update
```

The kernel is re-installed but is still getting that kernel panic message. How can I fix this?

Comment: Post a picture of the kernel panic.

Comment: @jordanm added a picture.

Comment: Maybe this: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=964335

Comment: @jordanm still unsolved i guess ?

Comment: Looks that way. I would just stick to an older kernel until it's resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing the `yum remove` or `yum update` you should be able to `yum install kernel-<ver>` where `<ver>` is a specific version number. Also you can have multiple kernels installed.

It's usually advised to keep a couple around for situations like this. When the system boots up you can select from one of the kernels to boot the system up.